# Jenkins Pipeline script -> Send email

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline project and want to send out an email.

I did set up the SMTP settings for Jenkins (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification) and could successfully send a test mail by using the "Test Settings" button.

But if I use my Pipepline project with the following pipeline script:

```
post {
    always {
        emailext body: 'A Test EMail!3', recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], subject: 'Test 999'
    }
}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Connection error sending email, retrying once more in 10 seconds...
```

Is there another place where I have to configure SMTP settings?

Comment: which plugin are you using to send email? are you using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure email notification in the Configure Jenkins page

Comment: Did that and also could send the test mail!

Comment: Any luck with that? I am facing this issue today